# Meta slider plugin only works after first refresh - Object has no method 'flex slider'

Tags: plugins, javascript

I have a wordpress theme I am using called 'Nordic', however I did not like their slider plugin, so I used my own... '[Metaslider][1]'

The problem is when you first load the page, the slider does not appear, and I get the following javascript error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider'
```

...however when I refriesh the page, the slider appears as normal.

To view the slider, please go to http://www.think-ag.com/ then click the yellow Coleman's image (8th one). As soon as this loads you will notice there is no slider, then refresh, you will now see the slider.

Also when I link straight to the page http://www.think-ag.com/?portfolio=ciknabs the slider loads first time.

I am not sure how the refresh fixes the error, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 versions of jQuery loaded on your page (one near the top, the default one from WordPress, and one near the bottom, loaded from google CDN). You should only have one. That is unrelated I think but it could be problematic in the future.

The colemans page is loaded with AJAX. It looks like it loads the page content, but not the page JavaScript. You will need to either switch theme, or include the Flex Slider JavaScript & CSS on every page so it is always present.

The easy way to do this is to just copy and paste these lines into your themes header.php file:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='metaslider-flex-slider-css'  href='http://www.think-ag.com/wp-content/plugins/ml-slider/assets/sliders/flexslider/flexslider.css?ver=2.6.3' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.think-ag.com/wp-content/plugins/ml-slider/assets/sliders/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=2.6.3'></script>
```

The, not so easy, but much nicer way is to use the `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` functions.

Then uncheck 'Print CSS' and 'Print JS' in the advanced slideshow options as you're including the JS and CSS manually, and there is no need for Meta Slider to enqueue it.